# Display related blog posts with specific tag what blogs contains - Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Display blog posts with a specific tag that blogs have - Shopify

For example, if the blog contains the tag Vegan, and needs to show related blogs that contain the tag Vegan,

if the blog has the tag is egg show related blogs with egg tag.

now my code now shows the same related blogs for all the blogs on the website, even if the tag doesn't match or is not applied to that blog. here is the blog with tags tinyurl.com/294769gb

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Related Recipes</h4>
<div class="res">
{% for article in blogs.Recipes.articles limit:8 %}
{% if article.tags contains 'Vegan' %}
<div class="njohn_search_otherpage"> 
<a href="{{ article.url }}" title="{{ article.title | escape }}"> 
<div class="crop">{{ article.image.src | img_url: 'medium' | img_tag: article.title }}</div> 
<div>{{ article.title }}</div> </a> </div>
 {% endif %} 
 {% endfor %}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: A blog doesn't have tags. Tags in a blog are the collection of tags in the articles. Could you rephrase the last sentence? Is not very clear what the current problem is.

Comment: @fabio-filippi the blogs do have tags. check here tinyurl.com/294769gb

Comment: That is a blog article.

Comment: yes, it is, what is wrong with that? I cant show related blogs inside the blog based on the tags?

Comment: Sorry, it's just confusing that you're talking about "blog" instead of "article". Is not clear what you're asking.